# PyCharm and VSCode not recognizing text file (Python)

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to read a text file and for some reason whenever I run my code, the only output is "Process finished with exit code 0."

Here is the code I have written

```
    message_file = open("TextFile1.txt", "r")
    content = message_file.read()
    print (content)
    message_file.close()
```

At this point I'm partially convinced the issue is where I have the text file saved. Right now it's located in the same file as this script.

I have tried moving it to C:\ where I had the first line changed to:

```
    message_file = open("C:\TextFile1.txt", "r")
```

From what I've read there shouldn't be an issue with the code itself but I'm probably mistaken.

I've also tried to create a text file where I write to it instead of read from it, and I get the same  "Process finished with exit code 0" output with nothing appearing in the text file.

```
    testfile = open("test.txt", "w")
    testfile.write("this is a test")
    testfile.close()
```

Thanks so much for you help!

Comment: File paths are relative to the working directory from which you execute the script. They are unrelated to the location of the script file.

Comment: This is probably a silly question but how do you change the directory where you execute the script in pycharm? I really appreciate the response

Comment: I don't see how the first program could terminate with exit code zero if the file isn't found. It should terminate with an IOError exception. I don't use PyCharm so I can't provide any advice about its use but I would recommend simply saving your program to a file with a `.py` extension (such as `x.py`) and in a terminal execute `python x.py`.

Comment: What command do you use to run your script?